# Hibernate - derived java classes for tables

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I generated mapping files and POJOs in Netbeans instead of writing them myself. Is it possible to use a derived class in a place of an inherited class? An example would be something like this:

```
Person.hbm.xml - mapping file

Person.java - generated class (strategy class per table)

PersonExtended - class that extends Person.java
```

So when I create a new object:

```
PersonExtended personextended = new PersonExtended(<parameters>);
```

Would I be able to call methods like:

`session.save(personextended) or session.delete(personextended)`

?

Is this scenario sensible or should I add any code that I need to in a generated class? Thanks in advance for help or suggestions.

-------Edit--------

In my database I don't have the typical structure that would be possible to be mapped as an inheritance. I merely want to keep the additional methods separate from the main java class for an entity.

Best Regards,
sass.

Answer (score 2):

you will have to tell hibernate how your extended classes should be mapped via a the hbm.xml file. Depending on the strategy Hibernate should use for polymorphism you might have to assign a descriminator value. there are 3 different strategies when using subclasses known as "table per class" "table per concrete class" and "table per subclass".

You can define subclasses in the hbm-xml file by using the `<subclass>` or `<joined-subclass>` elements

if you correctly defined your hbm.xml file you can then use `session.save(new PersonExtended())` or sth.

you can read up on this here:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

hope that helped..

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot for the answer. But I'm not sure about the proper use of this. If I were to auto-generate the hibernate classes from a database while having those mappings in mapping file, would the subclasses be generated as well? Or only the base classes would?